# CMake encounter an error while i build the Maven project

Tags: cmake

I tried to build the hadoop source code on my laptop(Windows 7), the Maven build job encountered an error. the detailed information as below:

```
     [exec] CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindPa
ckageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
     [exec]   Could NOT fi-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
     [exec] See also "C:/cygwin64/home/jding27/hadoop-2.7.1-src/hadoop-common-pr
oject/hadoop-cond ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
     [exec] Call Stack (most recent call first):
     [exec]   C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.6mmon/target/native/CMakeFile
s/CMakeOutput.log".
     [exec] /Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MES
SAGE)
     [exec]   C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake:124
(FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
     [exec]   CMakeLists.txt:107 (find_package)
     [exec]
     [exec]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have already configured the Windows System Environment variables below:
ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\zlib128\include

ZLIB_LIBRARY=C:\zlib128\lib\zdll.lib

Answer (score 1):

Those errors are not referring to environment variables, but to CMake variables that it was not able to determine. If you have `ZLib` not in `Program Files` you have to tell CMake where to find it with `ZLIB_ROOT`. Call

```
cmake -D ZLIB_ROOT:PATH=C:\zlib128 ....
```

**Reference**

- [FindZLIB CMake Module Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindZLIB.html)